# Consulta mediante Elocuent aplicando un Where sobre una tabla relacionada 1 a muchos

Tags: laravel-8

necesito hacer una consulta mediante Elocuent sobre un par de tablas que están relacionadas 1 a muchos y no estoy pudiendo resolverlo. A continuación, les pongo el código que estoy usando:

```
$datos = Vigelectrodetenida::query()
    ->with('relUsr')
    ->where('cam1b', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->busquedas . '%')
    ->orWhere('cam1c','LIKE', '%' . $this->busquedas . '%')
    ->orderBy($this->campOrden, $this->direcOrden)
    ->paginate(20);
```

Este código lo uso para generar una tabla que tiene un input de búsqueda utilizando livewire. Por ahora, las consultas que hago sobre el campo cam1b o cam1c funcionan bien, pero cuando quiero poner otro orWhere y que el mismo accione sobre el campo name que está en la tabla users (relUsr) deja de funcionar, me dice que no existe el campo name. A continuación les pongo el código que estoy usando y el error que se me está generando.

```
$datos = Vigelectrodetenida::query()
    ->with('relUsr')
    ->where('cam1b', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->busquedas . '%')
    ->orWhere('cam1c','LIKE', '%' . $this->busquedas . '%')
    ->orWhere('name','LIKE', '%' . $this->busquedas . '%')
    ->orderBy($this->campOrden, $this->direcOrden)
    ->paginate(20);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, espero haber podido transmitir correctamente mi duda y que me puedan ayudar.

Quiero agradecer a @HeytalePazguato por su valiosa ayuda

Comment: ya has tarbajado con wherHas?

Comment: Todas las sentencias `where` que encadenas buscan sobre campos de la tabla "registrada" para el modelo *Eloquent* que estas utilizando, no encuentra `name` porque no esta en dicha tabla.

Comment: Bro, pasa los campos de las tablas involucradas y te puedo dar una solución hecha.

Comment: En mi tabla si05_vigelec_dtosdetenida, tengo el campo id_usr y en la tabla users_dnpc tengo su clave principal que es id y el campo que quiero involucrar en la consulta where es el siguiente: name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Una forma de hacerlo es con `select()` y `join()`

La forma general de construirlo es así

```
$query = Modelo::select('tabla_del_modelo.*')->join('tabla_del_valor_foraneo', 'tabla_del_valor_foraneo.columna', '=', 'tabla_del_modelo.columna')
```

Donde:

- Modelo => El modelo en el que deseas mostrar la información.
- tabla_del_modelo => La migración (Tabla) del modelo anterior.
- tabla_del_valor_foraneo => La migración (Tabla) de la columna foránea que deseas agregar.
- columna => El nombre de la columna dentro de la migración (Tabla) correspondiente.

Utilizando los datos que pusiste en tu pregunta y comentarios (Como no agregaste tus migraciones ni tus modelos tal vez tengas que adaptarlos)

```
$datos = Vigelectrodetenida::select('si05_vigelec_dtosdetenida.*')->join('users_dnpc', 'users_dnpc.id', '=', 'si05_vigelec_dtosdetenida.id_usr')
```

Después de eso ya puedes agregar tus `where()`, y todos los campos que sean de la tabla `users_dnpc` tendrán que declararse a través del nombre de la tabla, por ejemplo:

```
->orWhere('users_dnpc.name','LIKE', '%' . $this->busquedas . '%')
```

**Nota:** Si existe alguna columna que tenga el mismo nombre en las dos tablas (Por ejemplo, en caso de que uses `created_at` y `updated_at`) tendrás que declararlas a través del nombre de la tabla, es decir, `users_dnpc.created_at` y `si05_vigelec_dtosdetenida.created_at`

Comment: Espectacular!!!, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, problema resuelto gracias a tu valioso aporte.

Comment: No hay de qué, que tengas un buen día